# jquery won't append select options of a field into another

Tags: jquery, laravel

I am working on a laravel project i have a form that displays a bootstrap modal when you click the add button, i want to load the select options of the course field into the select of the level modal (that shows when you click the add button) using jquery, but it keeps showing me nothing.
[image]
Course and level form code

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
<label for="program">Course</label>
<div class="input-group">
<select class="form-control" name="program_id" id="program_id">
<option value="">------------</option>
@foreach($programs as $key =>$p)
<option value="{{$p->program_id}}">{{$p->program}}</option>
@endforeach
</select>
<div class="input-group-addon">
<span class="fa fa-plus" id="add-more-program"></span>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-5">
<label for="level">Level</label>
<div class="input-group">
<select class="form-control" name="level_id" id="level_id">
</select>
<div class="input-group-addon">
<span class="fa fa-plus" id="add-more-level"></span>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

script code

```
$('#add-more-level').on('click', function(){
        var programs = $('#program_id option');
        var program = $('#frm-level-create').find('#program_id');
        $(program).empty();
        console.log(program);
        $.each(programs, function(i,pro){
            $(program).append($("<option/>",{
                value : $(pro).val(),
                text : $(pro).text(),
            }))
        })
        $('#level-show').modal('show');
    });
```

part of level modal code

```
<div class="modal fade" id="level-show" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelled-by="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">New level</h4>
        </div>
        <form action="{{route('postInsertLevel')}}" method="post" id="frm-level-create">
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <select class="form-control" name="program_id" id="program" placeholder="program_id"></select>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Is there something wrong with my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is in this line:

```
var program = $('#frm-level-create').find('#program_id');
```

Change it to:

```
var program = $('#frm-level-create').find('#program');
```

Moreover, the **for** attribute of your labels are wrong. I changed them, like from:

```
<label for="program">Course</label>
```

to:

```
<label for="program_id">Course</label>
```

The snippet:

```js
$('#add-more-level').on('click', function(){
    var programs = $('#program_id option');
    var program = $('#frm-level-create').find('#program');
    $(program).empty();
    //console.log(program);
    $.each(programs, function(i,pro){
        $(program).append($("<option/>",{
            value : $(pro).val(),
            text : $(pro).text(),
        }))
    })
    $('#level-show').modal('show');
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="col-sm-4">
    <label for="program_id">Course</label>

    <div class="input-group">
        <select class="form-control" name="program_id" id="program_id">
            <option value="">------------</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
        </select>

        <div class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="fa fa-plus" id="add-more-program"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-5">
    <label for="level_id">Level</label>

    <div class="input-group">
        <select class="form-control" name="level_id" id="level_id">
        </select>

        <div class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="fa fa-plus" id="add-more-level">add-more-level</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>



<div class="modal fade" id="level-show" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelled-by="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">New level</h4>
            </div>
            <form action="{{route('postInsertLevel')}}" method="post" id="frm-level-create">
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <select class="form-control" name="program_id" id="program"
                                    placeholder="program_id"></select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It works perfectly Thank you! but can you explain to me why the label should be `program_id` ?

Comment: @Pain the attribute **for** of a label refers to the id of the element to which it is attached. You may take a look to [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label). I hope this help you. Can you upvote? Thanks

Comment: Done! Thanks for the help